# Limit and summation in Python

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, math, sympy, diff

I am trying currently to calculate the limit of the following formula:

[image]

I tried the following code:

```
nsum(lambda k: ((x)**(2k))/fac(2k), [0, inf])
```

where `x = np.pi/2`
it returned the following message:

```
 File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_14/335.py", line 3
    nsum(lambda k: ((-1)**2*(x)**(2k))/fac(2k), [0, inf])
                                   ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I tired this too:

```
sym.limit((np.pi/2)**(2k))/fac(2k), k, sym.oo)
```

I got the same error:

```
File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_14/40.py", line 1
    sym.limit(((np.pi/2)**(2k))/fac(2k), k, sym.oo)
                                    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I could not figure out where my problem lies, any idea would be appreciated.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `2*k`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With Python, multiplication needs to be written explicitly. In your case, you need to write `2*k`.

Edit: it is clear that this is your first time with Python and the distinction between numerical and symbolic libraries. Here, I'm going to discuss SymPy and the way I would approach your problem:

```py
from sympy import var, Sum, pi, factorial, limit
# create symbols n and k
var("k, n")
# create a symbolic expression.
# NOTE: I have replace the upper limit n with infinity
expr1 = Sum((pi / 2)**(2 * k) / factorial(2 * k), (k, 0, oo))
expr1.doit()
# output: cosh(pi/2)

# If you wanted to compute the limit of the original expression:
expr2 = Sum((pi / 2)**(2 * k) / factorial(2 * k), (k, 0, n))
limit(expr2, n, oo)
# It throws an error!
```